# blueimp jquery upload widget partially overwritten by appended view

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, blueimp

I have the plugin working perfectly using codeigniter 2.1. I am now trying to use the plugin as part of a dynamically generated page, made up of several views.

To do this my controller contains the following:

```
$this->load->view('blue_view_widget'); // the file upload view
$this->load->view('form'); // a form
```

I now see that the template-upload and template-download table (which is generated by javascript) is overwritten by the html from the form view. I'm thinking ( maybe incorrectly ) that the html from the second view is echo'ed out before the javascript has time to dynamically generate the table at the bottom of the view. How can I fix this ?

This is my code:

```
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
<!--    <tr class="template-download fade">-->
    <tr class="template-download ">
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td></td>
            <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else { %}
            <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
            {% } %}</td>
            <td class="name">
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
            </td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="delete">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
                <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                <span>{%=locale.fileupload.destroy%}</span>
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
<script src="blueimp/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<!-- The Templates plugin is included to render the upload/download listings -->
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Templates/tmpl.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Load-Image/load-image.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS and Bootstrap Image Gallery are not required, but included for the demo -->
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/js/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
<script src="blueimp/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
<script src="blueimp/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload file processing plugin -->
<script src="blueimp/js/jquery.fileupload-fp.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload user interface plugin -->
<script src="blueimp/js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
<!-- The localization script -->
<script src="blueimp/js/locale.js"></script>
<!-- The main application script -->
<script src="blueimp/js/main.js"></script>
<!-- The XDomainRequest Transport is included for cross-domain file deletion for IE8+ -->
<!--[if gte IE 8]><script src="js/cors/jquery.xdr-transport.js"></script><![endif]-->


THE SECOND VIEW ('FORM') BEGINS HERE.


 <div class="container">
         <base href="http://localhost/bootstrap1/">
<!--  <div class="row">-->
 <fieldset>

            <legend>Registration</legend>      


  <div class="span10" class="well">

        <form class="well" id="registerHere" method='post' action='index.php/site/process_form'>
//        



<div class="form_row" >

    <div class="control-group">  
            <label class="control-label" for="textarea">Textarea</label>  
            <div class="controls">  
              <textarea class="span8" class="input-xlarge" id="description" name="description" rel="popover" data-content="Re-enter your description." data-original-title="description" rows="3"></textarea>  
            </div>  
          </div>  
</div>    


<div class="form_row" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think of the 'link rot'. In any case the following is the answer to the question:

I am using the the bootstrap toolkit and am trying to make self contained views inside bootstrap container tags. The way I have it set up is:

header

view A:  HTML goes here  css and js

view B:  HTML goes here  css and js

footer

when I concatenated the 2 views , I had a duplicate jquery script, causing in my case the following error in firebug:

```
$(”#fileupload”).fileupload is not a function
[Break On This Error] 

$(’#fileupload’).fileupload();
```

I still don’t understand what it means, given my poor JS skills at present, but once I commented out the second script the whole page started working as expected.